# Object registration kinect with ICP and orientation

Tags: object, kinect, registration, point-clouds

I am trying to register a small symmetric object (Ex: a cube) using point clouds from kinect. I am rotating the object around its axis and getting point clouds of the object at orientations at 0, 90, 180, 270 degrees w.r.t. a global frame.

Now, I would like to combine all these four individual point clouds into one point cloud that represents/models the object. For this I would like to use ICP and the orientation information. Is there any approach that takes advantage of the orientation information to be used with Iterative Closest Point (ICP) approach ?

Or is there any other simpler way to do this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities:

- Use the known transform to initialise the algorithm.
- Incorporate distance from the known alignment into
  the error cost used in the alignment phase.